# ProxyPass Port 110

Tags: apache, proxypass

Is it possible to proxypass port 110 the same as ports 80 and 443 can be?

I have tried the following and get error

> [warn] *default* VirtualHost overlap on port 110, the first has
>   precedence

My config:

```
<VirtualHost *:110>
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.100:110/
        ProxyPassReverse / http:10.0.0.100:110/
        ServerName yambuk.no-ip.biz
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You probably need the VirtualHost to bind `*:80`, the ProxyPass syntax looks correct

Comment: I am running 2 webservers with the 1 public ip address. trying to redirect the email to the correct server

Comment: Well Apache is an http server - mail is not http. The mail server should just listen directly on port 110, you don't need to proxy anything

Comment: I can get the http to redirect to the correct server, is there a way of getting each server to listen on port 110 and get the correct email.